# Python Selenium: Asserting text in element list

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, pageobjects

I am trying to cover a case where i need to see if a string is not present in a list of divs. The XPATH expression returns N amount of divs which contain text that i need to assert. Maybe you guys could help me out figuring this out? You can find my code below.

**Locator**:
locators.py

```
lines_all = (By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[8]/div/div[1]')
```

**Function**: numbers_page.py

```
def check_dem_lines(self):
    lines = self.driver.find_elements(*Locators.lines_all)
    return lines
```

**Test**: tests.py

```
def test_lines(self):
    main_page.find_number(number)
    number_lines = number_page.check_dem_lines()
    for lines in number_lines:
        if lines.text == 'String that should not be there':
            assert False
```

Comment: whats the problem you are getting. if there is an error then please provide a stack of same. please add the info in your question